# Android SQLite synch with Web PHP via JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, sqlite

I've got a web mysql DB that my Android app gets data from.  The DB on the web is similar to the one on the phone, and in several cases there are tables that need to be in synch.

Tables aren't huge, but there's a lot of text. Simplest approach would be to drop the tables and recreate them, then insert all the data again.  Even to my amateur coder mind, this is silly and hugely inefficient.

Here's what I've done, and this works... but my question is, Is there a smarter, simpler, or more refined way to do it.

```
 Android app sends request to web mysql. 
 Web returns the tables that must be in synch via JSON
 Android parses JSON
 Android queries each table for IDs
 Android loops through each table's IDs and within the loop, compares JSON IDs
       If ID is not on device, Insert this record.
       If ID is on device, but not in JSON, delete from device.
 Repeat for every table that needs to be in synch
```

I need certain parts of the DB to remain on the phone and be in synch, but I am just wondering if there is a built-in or more intelligent solution than this?

Thank you

Comment: Didn't get you that what you want?

Comment: Yes thank you -- this seems to work (Though I'm doing it in reverse, using a SELECT statement based on what's in an array of IDs from the JSON object.  Works, but still wondering if there is a better or more elegant solution.